# How to fix the sqlite database locked error even though I'm using separate *sql.DB for both functions?

Tags: sqlite, go

Here is a sample code that shows the error:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func DoSomething() {
    db1, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db1.Close()

    updatePhone, err := db1.Prepare("UPDATE People SET phone = ? WHERE person_id = ?")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer updatePhone.Close()

    // read db
    readStmt, err := db1.Prepare("SELECT * FROM people")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer readStmt.Close()

    var person struct {
        name    sql.NullString
        address sql.NullString
        phone   sql.NullInt64
    }

    // loop
    for {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        rows, err := readStmt.Query()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for rows.Next() {
            err = rows.Scan(&person.name, &person.address, &person.phone)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            if !person.phone.Valid {
                _, err = updatePhone.Exec(12345, person.name.String)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)
                }
            }
        }
        rows.Close()
    }
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    _, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People (person_id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, address TEXT, phone INTEGER)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stmt, err := db.Prepare("REPLACE INTO People (person_id, address) VALUES (?,?)")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    _, _ = stmt.Exec("A", "Street 1")
    _, _ = stmt.Exec("B", "Street 2")

    DoSomething()
}
```

The database gets filled with data periodically, the function `DoSomething` is supposed to keep reading the database in a loop. When I run this, I get error "database is locked".

The error occurs at this line:

```
_, err = updatePhone.Exec(12345, person.name.String)
```

Comment: `rows` is not being closed.

Comment: @mkopriva Added rows.Close() but still getting same error "database is locked". Can you please check if that's the correct place to put rows.Close()?

Comment: It could be that the `SELECT` query acquired a lock on the `people` table which won't be released until `rows.Close()` is executed, and therefore the `UPDATE` query gets stuck. I'd recommend you do the following: execute select query; loop over rows (with Next); scan each row into a person; append person into a slice of persons; after rows loop close the rows; then loop over the slice of scanned persons; execute update for each person.

Comment: @mkopriva i checked that, you are right. The read lock is preventing the write lock from being acquired.  Thank you.